# How to import a global Stylus file in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, stylus, stylus-loader

I want to use it for my global variables.

The fila I want to import just has this single line:

`primary = red`

But i can't import the file globally.

I tried in vue.config.js (_variables.styl is in the same folter, to avoid the route as an error factor)

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      stylus: {
        import: "./_variables.styl",
      },
    },
  },
};
```